# Ajax call from php file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to retrieve data from a php page to use in a flot chart. I am having trouble with the ajax call and I cannot figure it out.

Here is some of my php:

```
//Sort data into groups for chart
foreach($querieResult as $entry){
    if ($entry['GroupName'] == 'Blue'){
        $date = strtotime($entry['Date'] . ' UTC')*1000;
        $BlueData[] = array($date, $entry['OverallAverageHourlyEpisodes']);
    }    
}
//Put all data into single array to pass to JS file
$mergedData[]= array('label' => "Blue Team Data", 'data' => $BlueData);
//JSON encode data for JS file
echo json_encode($mergedData);
```

Which outputs:

```
[{"label":"Blue Team Data","data":[[1373500800000,"1.57"],[1381276800000,"12.89"],[1377475200000,"28.04"]]}]null
```

Here is my ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"getTeamPerformance.php",
    method: 'GET',
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        alert(data.label);
        alert(data.data);
    },
    error: function(errorGiven){
        document.write(errorGiven);
    }
});
```

I am trying to see if the data is passed through so on success I just have an alert.

When this is run I get the output:

```
[object Object]
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try `alert(JSON.stringify(data));` or better use `console.log(data)`

Comment: Agreed with @PSL -- log your data first and see what it is, I see you have an **array** of objects in your callback, so obviously `data.label` won't work. You'll probably need `data[0].label` -- but log it first, it helps greatly.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a header issue you need to specify it before your echo output.

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

Otherwise use `JSON.parse(response);`

Answer (score 0):

Data is an array, containing one object.

To access object use `data[0]`, for lable `data[0].label`

Wondering if the `null` at end is part of response....if so will cause invalid json parse error

Comment: The null is at the end of the php result. Could this be the problem?

Comment: shouldn't be anything outside of the root braces for the json. Paste repsonse  into jsonlint.com, never seen it lie